# preg_replace removes multiple "\n"s

Tags: php, preg-replace, line-endings

How do I remove multiple occurrences of `\n` from the sample below and replace with just one occurrence of `\n`?

Basically I just want to remove multiple line breaks and replace them with just one line break.

```
\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n \n\n \n\n\n\n\n\n\n    \n\n     \n\n     \n\n    \n\n    \n\n     \n\n     \n\n     \n     \n     \n     \n     \n     \n     \n\n     \n\n     \n\n     \nEDITION:  U.S.\n\n \nINTERNATIONAL\n\n     \nMÉXICO\n\n     \n\n     \nSet edition preference\n\n     \n\n     \n\n     \n\n     \nSign up\n\n     \nLog in\n\n     \n\n \n\n     \n\n     \n\n     \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n     \n\n     \n\n\n \n\n \n\n     \n\n     \n\n    \n\n    \n\n     \n\n     \nHome\n\n     \nVideo\n\n     \nNewsPulse\n\n \nU.S.\n\n     \nWorld\n\n     \nPolitics\n\n     \nJustice\n\n     \nEntertainment\n\n     \nTech\n\n     \nHealth\n\n     \nLiving\n\n     \nTravel\n\n \nOpinion\n\n     \niReport\n\n     \nMoney\n\n     \nSports\n\n     \n\n    \n\n\n\n\n\n \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n \n\n\n\n \n\n\n\n\n\n\n \n\nupdated 10:02 a.m.EDT, Fri June 3, 2011\n\n\n\n\n\n \n\n\n\n\n\nDr. Jack Kevorkian dead at 83\n\n\n\n\n\n\nThe Michigan pathologist who put assisted suicide on the world\'s medical ethics stage, apparently died of a blood clot, according to his attorney. FULL STORY
```

Comment: wouldn't matching "[\n]+" and replacing it with "\n" work?

Comment: PeterT I just tried your method, but now nothing is returned. idk why.

Comment: What code are you using to replace with.  PeterT has the right regex for this AFAIK

Comment: I need the multiple lines replaced with a single line, mario. So newlines I suppose.

Comment: PHP. current code is: echo $archive = preg_replace("[\n]+", "\n", $archive);

Comment: Seems like you  just forgot the [PCRE delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) then.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways

```
while(strpos($string, "\n\n") !== false)
  str_replace("\n\n", "\n", $string);
```

And

```
preg_replace("/\n+/", "\n", $string);
```

Comment: In my framework I am currently using hte first version because when I wrote it 6 years ago didn't know much about regex XD (I was kiddish too)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
<?php
$string = "\n\n\n\n Text \n\n Text \n\n\n\n\n Text \n\n\n";

echo preg_replace("#[\n]+#", "\n", $string);
```

Comment: Oh well :) Yours shows it without, so its all good. Thanks for the fyi though.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a real carriage return you can do this to remove successive carriage returns:

```
preg_replace('/\n+/', '\n', $yourString);
```

Else for the string '\n' you can do:

```
preg_replace('/(\\n)+/', '\n', $yourString);
```

Finally, if you want to remove all spaces in between your \n too you can do"

```
preg_replace('/\s*\n+/', '\n', $yourString);
```

Comment: For a linebreak to work, you need to enclose it in double quotes on at least the replaced part, IE `"\n"`.

Comment: The `\n` in the single quoted regex are correct (more advisable to have PCRE interpret the escape sequences). But the replacement string must indeed be filled by PHP with the correct character sequences.

Comment: only for the second case where we want to replace string '\n' we should keep the replacement part as single quote, others require double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing the `+` match to be greedy, by using `++` instead.

```
preg_replace('/\n++/', "\n", $yourString);
```

Comment: Problem you will have is you need `"` around the replacement `\n` for it to return a new line character.

Comment: Oh whoops. Sorry I Just copied it from another example without properly looking :P

Answer (score 0):

Strange, none of the code works?
Example:

```
$barcodes = "5312353123123



5312353123123



5312353123123";
echo(     var_dump(   $barcodes     )     . '</br>' . "\n"  );
$barcodes = preg_replace('/\n+/', "\n", $barcodes);
exit(  var_dump(   $barcodes     )     . '</br>' . "\n"  );
```

Output:

```
string(55) "5312353123123 5312353123123 5312353123123"
string(55) "5312353123123 5312353123123 5312353123123"
```

That means the function does... nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Another way from the gotcha's examples on the man page for str_replace() is:

```
// Order of replacement
$str     = "Line 1\nLine 2\rLine 3\r\nLine 4\n";
$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$replace = '<br />';

// Processes \r\n's first so they aren't converted twice.
$newstr = str_replace($order, $replace, $str);
```

Comment: FYI: `\R` is much more compact than `array("\r\n", "\n", "\r")` and have the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$newstr = preg_replace("/\r\n\r\n|\r\r|\n\n/", "..", $str);
```