# Trim multiple line breaks and multiple spaces off a string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, trim

How can I trim multiple line breaks?

for instance,

```
$text ="similique sunt in culpa qui officia


deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. 



Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore
"
```

I tried with this [answe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228367/preg-replace-remove-multiple-n)r but it does not work for the case above I think,

```
$text = preg_replace("/\n+/","\n",trim($text));
```

The answer I want to get is,

```
$text ="similique sunt in culpa qui officia

    deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. 

    Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore
    "
```

Only **single line break** is accepted.

Also I want to trim multiple white space at the same time, if I do this below, I can't save any line break!

```
$text = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', trim($text));
```

How can I do both thing in line regex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your line breaks in this case are `\r\n`, not `\n`:

```
$text = preg_replace("/(\r\n){3,}/","\r\n\r\n",trim($text));
```

That says "every time 3 or more line breaks are found, replace them with 2 line breaks".

Spaces:

```
$text = preg_replace("/ +/", " ", $text);
//If you want to get rid of the extra space at the start of the line:
$text = preg_replace("/^ +/", "", $text);
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/PmDE6cDm

Comment: if I do this, it will trim off all the line breaks `preg_replace("/(\s){2,}/"," ",trim($text))`

Comment: Answer updated. `\s` is for all whitespace, including newlines. For spaces just use an actual space character  Also be sure to use double quotes when strings have escaped characters (like `\n` or `\s`) in them

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way, but I would use explode. For example:

```
function remove_extra_lines($text)
{
  $text1 = explode("\n", $text); //$text1 will be an array
  $textfinal = "";
  for ($i=0, count($text1), $i++) {
    if ($text1[$i]!="") {
      if ($textfinal == "") {
        $textfinal .= "\n";  //adds 1 new line between each original line
      }
      $textfinal .= trim($text1[$i]);
    }
  }
  return $textfinal;
}
```

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: I know... this is why I included the disclaimer at the top saying that I am not sure if this was the best way. I guess I need to get my mind around the more sophisticated functions like preg_replace. :O)