# How do you trim white space on beginning and the end of each new line with PHP or regex

Tags: php, regex, whitespace, trim

How do you trim white space on beginning and the end of each new line with PHP or regex?

For instance,

```
$text = "similique sunt in culpa qui officia 

     deserunt mollitia animi, id est 

  laborum et dolorum fuga   

";
```

Should be,

```
$text = "similique sunt in culpa qui officia

deserunt mollitia animi, id est

laborum et dolorum fuga
";
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using a regex is certainly quicker for this task. But if you like nesting functions this would also [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) whitespace from all lines:

```
$text = join("\n", array_map("trim", explode("\n", $text)));
```

Comment: A regex is quicker? I tested my regex (`/[ \t]+$/m`) against your approach (just with `PHP_EOL` instead of "\n") and it is around 5 times slower (22,4ms vs 4,3ms for 1000 iterations over a ~900 char string).
And that regex is already two times faster than the other ones here, as it only removes trailing whitespace..

Answer (score 4):

```
<textarea style="width:600px;height:400px;">
<?php

$text = "similique sunt in culpa qui officia 

     deserunt mollitia animi, id est 

  laborum et dolorum fuga   

";

echo preg_replace("/(^\s+|\s+$)/m","\r\n",$text);

?>
</textarea>
```

I added the testarea so you can see the newlines clearly

Comment: thanks but I have a problem with this regex with another regex when I have multiple line breaks - `$text = preg_replace("/(\r\n){3,}/","\r\n\r\n",trim($text));` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328404/trim-multiple-line-breaks-and-multiple-spaces-off-a-string

Comment: with your regex, I cannot trim multiple line breaks anymore... how come?

Comment: I think my regex only works with the sample you gave, the linebreaks are lost in my method, then replaced. You are better off using @mario's solution - it is more robust, and probably more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

1st solution :

Split your original string with the newline character with [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) on each token, then rebuild the original string ...

2nd solution :

Do a replace with this regular expression \s*\n\s* by \n with [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [any horizontal whitespace character](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) switch and `preg_replace` function to replace them with nothing:

```
$text = trim(preg_replace('/(^\h+|\h+$)/mu', '', $text));
```

If you need preserve whitespace on file ned remove `trim` or replace with `ltrim` function

Answer (score 0):

Here another regex that trims whitespace on beginning an end of each line..

```
$text = preg_replace('/^[\t ]+|[\t ]+$/m', '', $text);
```

See [/m modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Answer (score -1):

Mario's solution works well (thank you for that mario - saved my day). Maybe somebody can explain though why it turned my later checks for cross-platform compatible line breaks such as

```
    (strstr($text, PHP_EOL))
```

to FALSE even when the line breaks existed.

Anyway, changing "\n" to PHP_EOL fixed the issue:

```
    $text = join(PHP_EOL, array_map("trim", explode(PHP_EOL, $text)));
```