# How to use Regex to remove redundant whitespace?

Tags: php, regex

I need a little bit of your help if you can.
I need the regular expression in php to remove multiple new lines and redundant whitespaces if occur more than 1.

```
for example

Hi    this  is
    a


test      code
```

------------------>
convert above into

```
Hi this is
a
test code
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use :

```
echo preg_replace("/(^\s+|\s+$)/m","\r\n",$text);
```

Ref: Link:

[How do you trim white space on beginning and the end of each new line with PHP or regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335060/how-do-you-trim-white-space-on-beginning-and-the-end-of-each-new-line-with-php-o)